# xcode 7.2, Swift "Show Live Issues" and autocomplete failure

Tags: xcode7

Symptoms:

- Successful build
- "Live Issues" shows tons of errors
- Autocomplete no longer works

This happened in the middle of coding, yet is unrelated to code changes. I have tried various other solutions I've found on here, including:

- Clean Build Folder
- Remove Derived Data
- Restart xcode (in combination with other items on this list)
- Restart computer
- Removing then re-adding the framework (referenced below*)
- Change build settings:

  - ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS `No` -> `Yes`
  - FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS nil -> `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and explicit path (non-recursive) to included framework
- Checkout code several changes back to ensure it's unrelated to code changes
- Build for actual device instead of simulator
- Changing the name of the file

None of the above works (the "Restart xcode" step was tried in combination with other steps above and in various orderings).

I am currently using xcode 7.2.1. (I couldn't upgrade to 7.3, but didn't see anything in the release notes about this issue anyway.)

*This project includes a framework that I have developed that is in a separate directory.

I've ruled out other solutions from stackoverflow, because:

- This project is swift
- I haven't created any precompiled headers (`find /var/folders -name SharedPrecompiledHeaders` yielded no results)

Again, the project builds. I can make changes and run and those changes make it out to the simulator. As far as I can tell, the Live Issues and code completion are just in a single file.

Comment: Note that changing the name of the file and rebuilding actually let autcompletion work for a minute or so (longer indexing period?) before showing the same symptoms as above.

Comment: After taking some steps above, it will appear that there are no Live Issue errors, but once I hit the space bar in the file in question, it loads up on errors (again, still compiles fine and runs fine).

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a "real" answer. In the end, I ended up checking out a revision so old that most of the code wasn't present.

I was pushing to a remote repository, checking out each branch and pushing, one of the branches was just the initial project autogenerated by xcode before it had any real code. Checking that branch out and checking out the current dev branch seems to have made the problem go away.

...for now